# Quasiparticle poisoning in fractional Josephson effect

Tags: superconductivity, majorana-fermions

It is predicted that in the presence of Majorana zero modes, which can mediate a current that is effectively carried by half of a Cooper pair, a Josephson junction can exhibit a periodicity of 4$\pi$. However, quasiparticle tunneling from the superconductor can restore the $2 \pi$ periodicity. Could someone explain why the latter process does not preserve fermion parity? Also any reference on quasiparticle poisoning is also appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean "why the latter process does not preserve fermion parity"?

Comment: @DanielSank quasi-particle have 1e charge, the $4\pi$-periodicity is due to the preservation of fermion parity, in the sense that only Cooper pairs (charge 2e) are allowed. Quasi-particles are not Cooper pairs, and break the fermion parity, reducing the $4\pi$ periodicity to the conventional $2\pi$.

Comment: @FraSchelle Thanks for the clarification. This is what confuses me, if quasi particle has 1e charge, how is it different from the supercurrent carried by 1e charge from half of a Cooper pair.

Comment: There is in principle no super-current carried by charge 1e, where did you read this ? By definition a super current is a current carried by Cooper pairs...

Comment: @FraSchelle This in Alicea's review paper. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.1293v1.pdf In section VB, "$I_e$
originates from tunneling ‘half’ of a Cooper pair across the junction and exhibits 4π periodicity in ∆φ. The first property is easy to understand: Cooper-pair hopping dominates the Josephson current in conventional s-wave superconductors because the bulk gap suppresses single-electron tunneling, but since HΓ couples zero-modes this suppression disappears"

Comment: @SlipStream Be careful, the half-Cooper-pair Alicea is talking about is an unpaired Majorana mode I think. This one has no charge at all. It is indeed a quasi-particle, but it's degenerate since it is at zero energy. So you can make them real by superposition, and then uncharged. If you have enough energy to bring this superposition above the gap, you split the degeneracy and recover a quasi-particle, which itself participate to poisoning.